# Open set in $Q_{p}$ is finite or countable union of open balls?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, model-theory, p-adic-number-theory

For $\mathbb{R}$, o-minimality gives that an open set is a finite union of open intervals and points, but is there anything similar for the $p$-adic numbers? I looked at $p$-minimality but this doesn't give any good way of decomposing the open sets in $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ similar to what $o$-minimality gives us. Since $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ is a metric space, open sets are at least infinite unions of open balls, but can we reduce this to finite unions (or at least countably unions)?

Thank you.

Comment: Since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb Q_p$, it is a separable metric space, thus Lindelöf.

Comment: It is certainly not true that every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a finite union of open intervals and points. (Counterexample: $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$). o-minimality only tells us about *definable* sets.